# Using Local Resource in a TemplateField

Tags: asp.net, localization

What's the right syntax for using a Local Resource string in a TemplateField in a GridView control?

When using a **Global** Resource in a TemplateField in a GridView control, this is the syntax I use.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$Resources:ItemList, Behavioral %>">
```

What's the correct syntax for **Local**, Assuming that my `.ascx` file is called `Graph2Table.ascx.resx`?